How to have a solid fill column indicator when line spacing is greater than zero?
Switching from fill-column-indicator (sadly too many issues now, but it was a good run) to native display-fill-column-indicator has left me with some unsightly gaps:

(setq-default line-spacing 0.25)

(setq-default display-fill-column-indicator-column 79)
(global-display-fill-column-indicator-mode 1)

I've tried adding :box or :stipple attributes to the fill-column-indicator face, but have been unable to achieve my desired result of a single solid line, like so:

Is there a way to have an increased line-spacing with a solid display-fill-column-indicator?

Did you read Displaying Boundaries in the Emacs manual? They say that the default is U+2502 if it can be displayed, falling back to |. You might try playing around with that, or maybe defining your own combining character somehow that displays as a longer vertical bar.

I did — that's how I learned that fill-column-indicator was the face to adjust — but no character makes a seamless line with my line spacing.

In hopes that this helps anyone else, the solution was two-fold:

Be sure to have an Emacs build that supports :stipple (some are lacking, as discovered at https://github.com/jdtsmith/indent-bars?tab=readme-ov-file#compatibility)
Use an empty space and a :stipple in lieu of any other character; the stipple width should be set to window-font-width

(setq-default line-spacing 0.25)

(setq-default display-fill-column-indicator-column 79)
(setq-default display-fill-column-indicator-character ?\ )
(set-face-attribute 'fill-column-indicator nil :background nil :foreground "white" :stipple '(7 1 " "))
(global-display-fill-column-indicator-mode 1)

The result, with a very visible white fill column indicator example:

